# UITableViewCell contentView has wrong height

Tags: ios, uitableview, setcontentview

I subclassed a UITableViewCell and its contentView has a height of 79px while the cell itself has a height of 80px. I tried changing the contentView frame but that didn't work.

The table view has no separator lines and the cell delete button has a 1px line beneath it which doesn't look good. I think this derrives from the 1px difference in the height of the contentView and the cell.

How can I set the same height for the contentView and the cell?!

Comment: if cell has a height of 80, your min pixel will will be 0 and max pixel will be 79, if you place any thing at pixel 80, it will be invisible or cells will overlap.

Comment: How can I remove that invisible 1 pixel line? I'd like the table cells to flush without a gap between them (and no separator lines).

Comment: use this funtion: -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and return 80/79, give both numbers a try, if non worked, try 81

Comment: Still doesn't work (http://cl.ly/V34x yellow BG color is the cell.backgroundColor and the pinkish color is the contentView.backgroundColor) the cells overlap and the cell's background color is visible when editing...

Comment: Show me your nib and code, make sure , size inspector is selected, while capturing the screen!

Comment: My cellForRowAtIndexPath method and the nib with cell & contentView selected: http://cl.ly/V3ev The rest of the code isn't special, I already stripped it down to the bare minimum.

Comment: You have accidentally changed or added something in your nib file! delete this nib file and make new! hopefully this problem will be resolved.

Comment: Still the same. Cell height is 80px and contentView is 79px. There must be a way to have the same height for both views...

Comment: Now you have two things, Cell and Content, set Cell Color what is required like pinkish, set content Color Default Color(or pinkish color as well), As Cell is always greater than Content, so line will remain visible, so both color should be same to avoid lining, or upper view(which is content) should have no color! Let me know if it worked!

Comment: Yes, this works to some extent. But it looks bad when the delete button is shown (http://cl.ly/V4EA).